# How to disable dependencies deduplication for one particular task

Tags: pyinvoke

I have a task like this:

```
@task(pre=[test_teardown, test_bootstrap], post=[test_teardown])
def test_do(c):
    pass
```

`test_teardown` post-task will not run because of task deduplication, but I want it to run before and after the `test_do` task.

I have tried using a `Collection` and overriding its default configuration [as described here](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/stable/concepts/configuration.html):

```
test = Collection(
    "test",
    bootstrap=test_bootstrap,
    teardown=test_teardown,
    do=test_do,
)
test.configure({"tasks": {"dedupe": False}})
namespace = Collection(test)
```

But `test_teardown` still gets deduplicated.

How can I disable deduplication for this particular task, so that I don't have to specify `--no-dedupe` on the command line and still have deduplication for other tasks?

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is to specify a dummy parameter for the task that I do not want to be deduplicated. Then I call the teas with different arguments for the dummy parameter. This way, it is not deduplicated (see the box with a note in the [docs](https://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/stable/concepts/invoking-tasks.html#task-deduplication)).

Example:

```
@task
def test_teardown(c, dummy):
    pass

@task(pre=[call(test_teardown, dummy="pre"), test_bootstrap], post=[call(test_teardown, dummy="post")])
def test_do(c):
    pass
```